# Waiting message for Store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have grid and relating store. How to add waiting message to grid while store update the some record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the `loadMask` property of the [GridPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel) :

> loadMask : Object An Ext.LoadMask
>   config or true to mask the grid while
>   loading. Defaults to false.

So, adding `loadMask:true,` in your GridPanel config should work.